# How to handle exceptions in a Django migration?

Tags: python, django, exception, migration

How do I catch an exception in a Django migration?

I have a migration that, because of various legacy reasons, I expect to fail sometimes. I want to be able to catch that error and run some error handling code in that case.

Specifically, I'm renaming a table, and sometimes the destination table already exists and I want to merge the contents of the old and new tables, then delete the old one.

I'm running Django 1.7 ( :( ) and we're planning on upgrading to 1.8 but it hasn't happened yet.

My migration is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0007_migration_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelTable(
            name='table_name',
            table='LegacyTableName',
        ),
    ]
```

When I run this, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File ".../django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File ".../django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File ".../django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File ".../django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File ".../django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File ".../django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File ".../django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File ".../django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File ".../django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    new_model._meta.db_table,
  File ".../django/db/backends/schema.py", line 350, in alter_db_table
    "new_table": self.quote_name(new_db_table),
  File ".../django/db/backends/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File ".../django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 129, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File ".../MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File ".../MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'LegacyTableName' already exists")
```

All that's provided in the migration itself is the `operations` list, and there doesn't seem to be an optional error-handling parameter in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#altermodeltable).

How do I catch the OperationalError so I can run some Python to merge the tables?

Comment: you have not mentioned what your backend is. The answer to this question is very much dependent on it.

Comment: Percona, but I was hoping to handle this in Python in a more generic way.

Comment: Fraid that would be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with trying to catch database exceptions in Python is that they may not be specific enough - e.g., `OperationalError` could arise for various reasons (only one of which is that the table name has already been changed).

I would suggest that rather than trying to catch exceptions you write your own migration function that does whatever checks/modifications are necessary. See the [documentation on `RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runpython).

> This is generally the operation you would use to create data migrations, run custom data updates and alterations, and anything else you need access to an ORM and/or Python code for.

In your case you would write a function that checks whether the table exists and performs some actions for either case.

There are some database-specific issues to be aware of when writing these functions, e.g., :

> on PostgreSQL, for example, you should avoid combining schema changes and RunPython operations in the same migration or you may hit errors.